# flatten too many nested object observable

Tags: rxjs, flatten

I have one object which contains a few levels of nested collection properties that need to be flattened. here is my observable:

```
const source1$ = of(
  {
    code: '00a',
    data: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'jon',
        jobs: [
          {
            name: 'developer',
            level: [
              1
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'smith',
        jobs: [
          {
            name: 'driver',
            level: [
              2, 3
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
    ]
  });
```

now I want to become something like the object below with help of rxjs operators. I try to do it with map,reduce,pluck but couldn't reach the goal.

```
{
  code: '00a',
  data: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: 'jon',
        jobs: 'developer(1)'

      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: 'smith',
        jobs: 'driver(2,3)'
      }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Okay, about your indentation... is there a semantic to your desired output having `data` indented twice, but `code` only indented once or is indentation arbitrary in your display scheme?

Comment: Yes, Just my indentation in my scheme. I just need jobs property to become string with related values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want something like this:

```ts
source1$.pipe(
  map(v => ({
    ...v,
   data: v.data.map(d => ({
      ...d,
      jobs: d.jobs.map(j => `${j.name}(${j.level.join()})`).join('-')
    }))
  }))
)
```

**As a side note:** if your application is doing a lot of nested object updating like this, look into a library that implements lenses for you. They make this much nicer.

---

Update:

This is another possible way to do a similar thing. Here you mutate the data which comes with all the usual caveats.

```ts
source1$.pipe(
  map(v => {
    v.data.forEach(d => 
      d.jobs = d.jobs
        .map(j => `${j.name}(${j.level.join()})`)
        .join('-')
    );
    return v;
  })
);
```

Comment: not working, because add jobs:string to data instead of adding to each one of the object inside data.

Comment: I wish I knew what that means...

Comment: @FarbodKain Sure, updated?

Comment: sorry for the bad explanation, I posted my solution which is just like yours with a little difference, and I'm curious is it possible to do this better?

Comment: @FarbodKain Depends what you mean by "better". I showed another way you could do this by mutating the data. :)

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this, and I'm looking for a better solution

```
    source1$
  .pipe(
    map(v =>
    ({
      ...v,
      data: v.data.map(x =>
      ({
        ...x,
        jobs: x.jobs.map(j =>
          `${j.name}(${j.level.join()})`
        ).join('-')
      })
      )
    })
    )
  )
  .subscribe(console.log)
```